# How do I open a jQuery dialog with a class instead of an id?

Tags: jquery, html, class, dialog

I have many links on a page that I need to open only a few jQuery dialogs with.  How do I open them using a class instead of an id?

Here is my script:

```
    <script>
    // increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
    $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
    $(function() {
        $( "#selectFolder" ).dialog({position:['middle',60],        
            open: function(event, ui) {  
            jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close").html('<span style="float:right;"><img src="../images/x.png" /></span>');  
        },  
            dialogClass: 'ui-widget-shadow',
            modal: true,    
            autoOpen: false,
            width: '650px',
            close: function(ev, ui) {$(this).close();}      
        });

        $( "#selectFolderOpen" ).click(function() {
            $( "#selectFolder" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="selectFolder" title="Select Folder">
        <div style="display:block;">
            <!--#include file="sidebar_modal_questions_folder_select.asp"-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is an example of what currently works:

```
<a href="#" class="buttonintable" id="selectFolderOpen">Select Folder</a>
```

I want it to work like this:

```
<a href="#" class="buttonintable selectFolderOpen">Select Folder</a>
```

That way I do not have to id every single link I want it to open in.

I know that you use a ('#selector') for and id and ('.selector') for a class - but I cannot get it to work.  Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your selector to `$('.selectFolderOpen').click(...)`

jQuery selectors can select anything that you would be able to target in a CSS selector.  It uses `#` to denote an id, and a `.` (dot) to denote a class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WVVXy/

```
$(function () {
  $("a.buttonintable").click(function () {
    $(this).dialog();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question.  Here is the working code:

```
<script>
// increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
$(function() {
    $( "#selectFolder" ).dialog({position:['middle',60],        
        open: function(event, ui) {  
        jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close").html('<span style="float:right;"><img src="../images/x.png" /></span>');  
    },  
        dialogClass: 'ui-widget-shadow',
        modal: true,    
        autoOpen: false,
        width: '650px',
        close: function(ev, ui) {$(this).close();}      
    });

    $( "a.selectFolderOpen" ).click(function() {
        $( "#selectFolder" ).dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Fire it with:

```
<a href="#" class="buttonintable selectFolderOpen">Select Folder</a>
```

Comment: The `a` in your selector `a.selectFolderOpen` can be deleted.  Maybe later you want to just make it a span or something for whatever reason :p  I tend to just use class names and not so narrowly scope them.